# itext, Flying Saucer: xhtml to pdf ClassCastException

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

```
public void createPDF() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(true);
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/comap/pages/admin/student.xhtml";
    try {
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocument(url);
        renderer.layout();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","C://user//first.pdf");
        java.io.OutputStream browserStream = response.getOutputStream();
        renderer.createPDF(browserStream);
        browserStream.close();
        session.invalidate();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

here is the exception..

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox cannot be cast to org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableBox

Comment: Great. Now only please add where exactly is the exception thrown, what is your question, what is the expected output... you know, the standard stuff.

Comment: It looks like data error in the XHTML. Run the above code on ever smaller XHTML files, till you find what XML caused the error. Validate the XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

This [commit](https://github.com/philcali/flyingsaucer/commit/e653850a67b06a08364030a51e5ae4a855213016) has fixed the issue. You can [download the Class](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/philcali/flyingsaucer/e653850a67b06a08364030a51e5ae4a855213016/flying-saucer-core/src/main/java/org/xhtmlrenderer/layout/BoxCollector.java) and place it in your src directory so that you don't have to rebuild the jar.